# Under what conditions do the payoffs from a to h make (U, L) a profile of strategies that constitutes a unique Nash equilibrium in pure strategies?

Tags: nash-equilibrium

[image]

I think the conditions that should be made are a>c and a>e, b>f and b>d. 
Also g

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If U and L are dominant strategies (U,L) will be a unique NE. The players believe that a deviation in their own strategy will not cause deviations by any other players.